# Makefile error: undefined reference to 'function'

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

I have an eclipse (Kepler) c/c++ project with an existing makefile and I want to add a new include path.

The path of the header files is: C:\devkitPro\tonclib\include

I added the path to the project settings under C/C++ General, Paths and Symbols and I tried to include the path via the "-I/c/devkitPro/tonclib/include" in the makefile.

Somehow the .h –files are included, but now I get strange errors:

```
make all 
Source: main.c metr.c
linking cartridge
main.o: In function `obj_test':
c:/Users/Christoph/gba_dev/Test/source/main.c:27: undefined reference to `key_poll'
c:/Users/Christoph/gba_dev/Test/source/main.c:40: undefined reference to `__key_curr'
c:/Users/Christoph/gba_dev/Test/source/main.c:40: undefined reference to `__key_prev'
c:/Users/Christoph/gba_dev/Test/source/main.c:40: undefined reference to `memcpy32'
main.o: In function `main':
c:/Users/Christoph/gba_dev/Test/source/main.c:66: undefined reference to `oam_init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/c/Users/Christoph/gba_dev/Test/Test.elf] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

And here is the current makefile:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Clear the implicit built in rules
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.SUFFIXES:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(DEVKITARM)),)
$(error "Please set DEVKITARM in your environment. export DEVKITARM=<path to>devkitARM)
endif

include $(DEVKITARM)/gba_rules

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TARGET is the name of the output, if this ends with _mb a multiboot image is generated
# BUILD is the directory where object files & intermediate files will be placed
# SOURCES is a list of directories containing source code
# DATA is a list of directories containing data files
# INCLUDES is a list of directories containing header files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TARGET      :=  $(shell basename $(CURDIR))
BUILD       :=  build
SOURCES     :=  source
DATA        :=  data
GRAPHICS    :=  gfx 
INCLUDES    :=  includes

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# options for code generation
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARCH    :=  -mthumb -mthumb-interwork

CFLAGS  :=  -g -Wall -O3\
        -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mtune=arm7tdmi\
        -fomit-frame-pointer\
        -ffast-math \
        $(ARCH)

CFLAGS  +=  $(INCLUDE)

CXXFLAGS    :=  $(CFLAGS) -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions

ASFLAGS :=  $(ARCH)
LDFLAGS =   -g $(ARCH) -Wl,-Map,$(notdir $@).map

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# any extra libraries we wish to link with the project
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBS    :=  -lgba

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# list of directories containing libraries, this must be the top level containing
# include and lib
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBDIRS :=  $(LIBGBA)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# no real need to edit anything past this point unless you need to add additional
# rules for different file extensions
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifneq ($(BUILD),$(notdir $(CURDIR)))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OUTPUT   :=  $(CURDIR)/$(TARGET)
export VPATH    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(CURDIR)/$(dir))

export DEPSDIR  :=  $(CURDIR)/$(BUILD)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# automatically build a list of object files for our project
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
CPPFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp)))
SFILES      :=  $(foreach dir,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.s)))
BINFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(DATA),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.*)))
BMPFILES    :=  $(foreach dir,$(GRAPHICS),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.bmp)))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# use CXX for linking C++ projects, CC for standard C
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ifeq ($(strip $(CPPFILES)),)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CC)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    export LD   :=  $(CXX)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export OFILES   :=  $(addsuffix .o,$(BINFILES)) \
                    $(BMPFILES:.bmp=.o) \
                    $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o) $(CFILES:.c=.o) $(SFILES:.s=.o)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# build a list of include paths
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export INCLUDE  :=  $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDES),-I$(CURDIR)/$(dir)) \
            $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-I$(dir)/include) \
            -I$(CURDIR)/$(BUILD) \
            -I/c/devkitPro/tonclib/include

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# build a list of library paths
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export LIBPATHS :=  $(foreach dir,$(LIBDIRS),-L$(dir)/lib)

.PHONY: $(BUILD) clean

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(BUILD):
    @echo  Includes: $(INCLUDE)
    @[ -d $@ ] || mkdir -p $@
    @make --no-print-directory -C $(BUILD) -f $(CURDIR)/Makefile

all : $(BUILD)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clean:
    @echo clean ...
    @rm -fr $(BUILD) $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).gba

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
else

DEPENDS :=  $(OFILES:.o=.d)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main targets
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(OUTPUT).gba   :   $(OUTPUT).elf

$(OUTPUT).elf   :   $(OFILES)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The bin2o rule should be copied and modified
# for each extension used in the data directories
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This rule links in binary data with the .pcx extension
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.pcx.o :   %.pcx
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This rule links in binary data with the .bin extension
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.bin.o :   %.bin
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This rule links in binary data with the .raw extension
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.raw.o :   %.raw
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(bin2o)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This rule creates assembly source files using grit
# grit takes an image file and a .grit describing how the file is to be processed
# add additional rules like this for each image extension
# you use in the graphics folders 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.s %.h : %.bmp %.grit
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    grit $< -fts -o$*

-include $(DEPENDS)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
endif
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don’t know exactly what is causing this problem, because I never worked with makefiles before, but I think the .c-files according to the header files can’t be found. They are located in C:\devkitPro\tonclib\src.

Please can someone guide me to the right direction?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a `makefile` problem. The `make` tool is just outputting compilation errors: your `main.c` is using **undefined variables**.

Comment: The functions are declared in C:\devkitPro\tonclib\src. How can I tell eclipse that the .c-files are there?